# oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table A  with column code which contains values AB,BC

```
-----
code
-----
'AB','BC'
```

Table B has following row

```
------------------------------
AB   4  2  1   
------------------------------
-------------------------------
BC   1  2  3
--------------------------------
```

For AB there is an row entry in another table B and similarly for BC

i want to use IN clause for the column code

```
select regexp_substr(replace (a.code,'''',''), '[^,]+', 1, level) from  A a , C b 
WHERE a.id ='SC_1' AND a.id= b.id AND a.name = 'CODE'
connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(replace (a.code,'''',''), '[^,]*')) + 1
```

when i execute above sql there is no result , i think the IN clause require row rather comma separated.kindly let me know how to work out on this.

Comment: You REALLY need to split that code into two separate columns for performance not to be impacted. Maybe look at Virtual Columns http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/VirtualColumns_11gR1.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to split your `code` string across several rows. Try:

```
select * from B
where B.code in (
    select regexp_substr(code, '[^,]+', 1, level) from A
    connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(code, '[^,]*')) + 1)
```

Comment: i like this.  i probably would've had to do this with two queries and some scripting in between in the server language, or a stored procedure.  is connect-by available in mysql or many other db's besides oracle?

Comment: @Frederic thanks , i will try executing to check whether it works.

Comment: @jon_darkstar, you should be able to use `WITH` in other RDBMS. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510rielau/.

Comment: @Frederic it takes time for me, as i also have a where clause

Comment: @Frederic the query takes too much time.

Comment: @Suresh, do you mean it times out? Can you update your question with the query you're trying?

Comment: @Frederic not timing out , but takes 4 min or more for just one row of data which has 'FM','FR'  , forgot to say it has single quotes.

Comment: @Frederic any idea why it is too slow.

Comment: @Suresh, I don't understand what your updated query is supposed to do. Can you clarify what it should return and what `a.name` is, maybe with some examples? :)

Comment: @Frederic your query is fine , the problem is with the dblink for the table i m accessing that takes time.